# Nested Loops - A Third One?

Tags: java, loops, nested

Write a program that prints the following on the Screen:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

5 6 7 8 9 10 

6 7 8 9 10 

7 8 9 10 

8 9 10
```

I'm having a little trouble correcting the nested loops - I have it to look like that, the numbers won't stop at 10 though. The code prints this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

I'm a beginner programmer and need help with this - do you need a third loop inside of the nested loop already? Any help is appreciated! Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopProgram
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        for (int e=0; e<8; e++)
        {
            for (int f=1; f<=10; f++)
            {
                System.out.print(f + e + " ");
            }   
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a third loop?  What would that gain you?  Also, why are you adding `f` and `e` in the loop?  That makes no sense.

Comment: The numbers won't stop because you are printing `f+e`, which will go up to `17`, because the maximum numbers in the loop for `e` is `7` and for `f` is `10`...

Comment: You just need to make  `f=e` in your inner loop and print only `f`. then you are good to go.

Comment: If I take out the e in the addition of F + E it stops at 10 but loses the increments it's taking. As in it prints like this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (x8)

Comment: ... and before I can even write up a proper hint, five people have given away the answer. Way to go, people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two loops are enough.

The outer loop runs eight times, you've got that working already.

Your inner loop, however, always runs ten times, which is not what you want. You want the inner loop to run 10 times first, then only 9 times, then only 8 times etc. The trick here is to change the start or end value of that inner loop, like this:

```
for (int e=0;e<8;e++) {
    for (int f=e+1; f<=10; f++) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the second loop:

```
for(int f=e;f<=10;f++)
```

and for output

```
System.out.print(f+" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
for(int e=1;e<9;e++) {
    for(int f=e;f<=10;f++) {
        System.out.print(f+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This ouputs exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= 10; j++) 
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three loops is severe overkill. This can be done with a single loop and two counters.

```
public class LoopProgram {
  static final int LIMIT_1 = 8;
  static final int LIMIT_2 = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    while(b <= (LIMIT_1 + 1)) {
      System.out.print(a);
      if(a < LIMIT_2) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        a++;
      } else {
        System.out.println();
        a = b;
        b++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need two loops:
The outer one will run eight times and the inner one will begin at the value of the outer counter (thats what makes each line count up to ten but always start at the first value of last line + 1) and run while it's counter is less than 10.

Something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int e = i; e < 10; e++) {
        //print e + 1
    } 
}
```

You have to print e + 1 so that your lines do not begin at 0, but at one, going up to 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an explanation of how to work this sort of thing out for yourself. In the commonest cases of a for-loop, you should ask yourself three questions about the index variable:

1. What is the first value I want it to have?
2. Under what conditions do I want to do another iteration?
3. How should it change from iteration to iteration?

For your inner loop, the answers are:

1. e
2. f <= 10
3. f++

From that, it is easy to construct the loop, and you already have several examples of it written for you.